# Using Django Forms: How can i use the chosen value of a forms.ModelChoiceField within a userdef validation

Tags: django, forms, validation

I got the following model:

```
class currency(models.Model):
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    dollaramount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.currency
```

This Model contains 2 entrys with currency-value "$" and "€"

The currency-model is related with a ModelChoiceField within the following form, which has a userdefined validation "clean_amount" for checking the amount, depending which currency is actual choosen in the currencyfield from the from itself.

How can i do the compare inside the userdef-validation "clean_amount", if the value from the selected object is "$" or "€"?

```
from django import forms
from currencies.models import currency

class createform(forms.Form):
    currency = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = currency.objects.all())
    amount = forms.DecimalField(initial = 0)

    def clean_amount(self):
        currencyfield = self.cleaned_data['currency']
        amount = self.cleaned_data['amount']
        if amount < 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Amount must be at least 0.")

        #HERE I WANT TO CHECK
        choosencurrency = currencyfield.??????

        if choosencurrency == "$" :
           #check $amount
        if choosencurrency == "€" :
           #check €amount

    return amount
```

Comment: Are you trying to save the results of your form submission to a database?

Comment: yes, i want to save them into the model for submission to db...

Comment: Then you should be using a ModelForm, which maps the data to your model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this in `clean()`, not `clean_amount()`. From `clean` you can access `self.cleaned_data['amount']` and `self.cleaned_data['currency']`.

Comment: ok, but amount = self.cleaned_data['amount'] already works here in clean_amount() fine, only problem is how to access the self.cleaned_data['currency'].

Comment: so, if i write the code in clean() instead of clean_amount, what is the code for the ???? to access the values "$" or "€"?

Comment: I don't see what's unclear about the answer I gave.  That is the code to access them both in `clean`.

Comment: so self.cleaned_data['currency'] returns really a string which i can compare with == "$" or "€"? I tried this, but it doesnt work, is there anything else to do when i want this compare?

Comment: I just debugged here, and my variable choosencurrency contains: <currency: $> so, its a object i think, how can i read the "$" from its value? (im new at django/python and dont know how exactly to handy this)

Comment: ok habs -> choosencurrency = self.cleaned_data['currency'].currency , vielen Dank soweit!